# Yii Infinite scroll last row values repeating

Tags: php, jquery, yii, infinite-scroll

i implement the Yii infinite scroll extension. its working fine. its scrolling 10 by 10 from the database dynamically at last 10 values are repeated one more time.

i simply printing text values only but at last row ie last 10 values are repeated once.

i added my code here :

**site controller**

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                $total = Recipe::model()->count();

            $pages = new CPagination($total);
            $pages->pageSize = 10;
            $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

            $posts = Recipe::model()->findAll($criteria);

        $this->render('index', array(
                'posts' => $posts,
                'pages' => $pages,
            ));
```

my index page here:

```
<div id="posts">
<?php  foreach($posts as $rec):  ?>
```

```
 <?php $rec_id=$rec['recipe_id'];  $name=$rec['name']; ?>
<?php echo $name=$rec['name']; ?>
```

then i added my extension below

Answer (score 0):

Infinite scroll ( and yii-infinite scroll) stops querying the server when it it hits a 404 error. on the next page. Yii framework keeps returning the last results for page numbers greater than what the result has.

This is why you keep seeing duplicated rows at the end of the results.. to prevent this add this piece of code to your corresponding action in your controller.

```
if(isset($_GET['Model_page'])){
    if($model->search()->pagination->pageCount < $_GET['Model_page']+1){
        throw new CHttpException(404,'No More results');
    }
}
```

Where `Model_page` is to be substituted with `Post_page` etc depending on your model name and `$model->search()` is your `dataProvider`, if you have some other `dataProvider` please use that directly after it has been declared.

Comment: I am still facing the problem ,thanks in advance please can you elaborate with your code..